# How to run multiple inferences in parallel on CPU?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, inference

I've got some models implemented in PyTorch, where their performance is evaluated on a custom platform (wrapper around Pytorch, keeping overall interface).

This is really slow however: testing 10k CIFAR10 takes almost 30mins on a single CPU. My cloud farm has no GPU available, but is highly CPU-oriented with load of memory available. Thus I'm thinking about spawning multiple threads/processes to parallelize these inference tests.

I know this is not as trivial with Python due to GIL and Pytorch resource model; from some research I found `torch.multiprocessing.Pool`.

Is it the best way? How could I deploy say `N` inference tasks on `N` CPUs, and then collect the results into an array? I wonder whether some `torch.device` info must be handled or is done automatically.

Something like:

```
for task in inference_tasks:
    p = spawn(process)
    accuracy = inference(model, p)
    ....
    #collect results
    results.append(accuracy)
```

**Edit:** the inference predictions are all **independent** from each other. The `DataLoader` could be copied and fed to each process to do the inference, then collect all the results.

Comment: You should try using 1. running a batch of data in a single forward pass 2. using `torch.set_num_threads` and 3. using jit (torchscript) before trying multiprocessing.

Comment: @arrmansa: I should say the tasks are completely independent from each other. Only final result should be collected in the main process.

Comment: so do you have multiple models or is it just one model?

Comment: @arrmansa: yes I have multiple models (actually I create N of them).

Comment: Existing answer is fine for processing within a single script. But you might consider using a proper inference server with multiple distinct workers. [link](https://www.auroria.io/running-pytorch-models-for-inference-using-fastapi-rabbitmq-redis-docker/). [link](https://github.com/kheyer/simple_cpu_embedding_server)

Answer (score -1):

Parallelism is pretty simple in python. The trickiness comes in how to divide up your job, and that sharing memory/state is hard and/or time consuming. Your ideal parallelisable function takes few/small inputs and returns few/small outputs. `sum(range(N, M))` is pretty ideal. It take two integers as input and returns one integer. Example:

```py
import os
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, as_completed

# job to parallelise computation of sum(range(N, M))
N = 0
M = 1_000_000_000
range_ = range(N, M)

with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=os.cpu_count()) as pool:
    # compute batch size
    chunk_size, remainder = divmod(len(range_), os.cpu_count())
    if remainder:
        chunk_size += 1


    # split job into roughly equal size chunks
    futures = []
    for i in range(os.cpu_count()):
       fut = pool.submit(sum, range_[i*chunk_size:(i+1)*chunk_size])
       futures.append(fut)

    # process results as and when they become ready
    total = 0
    for future in as_completed(futures):
        total += future.result()

print(f'{total=}')
```

`max_workers=os.cpu_count()` is not strictly needed, as this is the default behaviour of `ProcessPoolExecutor`.

Comment: Let me ask: why are you not using torch's implementation (afaik it's recommended over python's default one). BTW, my tasks are completely independent from each one: all I need is firing them, then collect the results? I guess the DataLoader can be copied and given to each process to do the inference on.